# Consume complex data type from ASP.net webservice via Coldfusion on Railo

Tags: asp.net, arrays, web-services, coldfusion, railo

I have an ASP.net webservice that returned a dataset to a Coldfusion consumer. It worked fine while I was hosting my CFML with CF9 Server. But now that I've switched to use Railo, it returns an error. You can get the details of this here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/railo/4I2iNrzctlQ

If you've got an answer to my Google Groups question feel free to let me know, however...

...the more I've read about this though, the more I'm finding it's not a good idea to return complex ASP.net types in a webservices, especially if I'm trying to consume from another platform - like CF.

So I decided to send back an array of data, but this is proving to be troublesome too. I've created a super basic WebMethod trying to return a String Array. When I try to return the array I get this error:

; nested exception is:
java.lang.NullPointerException

Here's the ASP.net code:

```
[WebMethod]
public String[] testWebMethod()
{

    String[] myString = new String[1];
    myString[0] = "test";

    return myString;

}
```

I'm pulling my hair out here. Any help please!!!!

Comment: Can you provide the CFML please?